# Jackson - deserializing Map implementation as HashMap

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

So, I have configuration

```
.defaultTyping(NON_FINAL)
```

which is writing correctly serialized json as:

```
"headers": [
        "org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders",
        {
```

Now, the problem is that MessageHeaders class is implementing Map, but also overrides put method so it throws an exception. In order to properly deserialize this I would need eaither to be able to serialize this as HashMap, so:

```
"headers": [
        "java.util.HashMap",
        {
```

or to be able to explicitly deserialize MessageHeaders as HashMap (since it is actually just Map.

Once more question is: how to serialize Object implementing Map as HashMap, or how to have Object implementing Map deserialized as HashMap.

Comment: Did you try @JsonDeserialize(as = java.util.HashMap.class) annotation?

Comment: Yes I did. The exception thrown is that MessageHeaders cannot be deserialized as HashMap. MessageHeaders implements Map interface only. Internaly it has final Map headers property which is used for storing this values.

Comment: I also tried @JsonSerialize(as=Map.class) but I assume that default typing NON_FINAL  takes precedance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found how to do this with custom serializer (the trick was to tell serializer to use java.util.HashMap instead of the real class name):

```
public class MessageHeadersJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MessageHeaders>{
    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(MessageHeaders value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        typeSer.writeTypePrefixForObject(value, gen, HashMap.class);
        serialize(value, gen, serializers);
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForObject(value, gen);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(MessageHeaders value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : value.entrySet()){
            gen.writeFieldName(entry.getKey());
            gen.writeObject(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

And then just registered it as a MixIn:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MessageHeadersJsonSerializer.class)
public abstract class MessageHeadersMixIn {}
```

And on parent object I'm deserializing it as HashMap:

```
public abstract class GenericMessageMixIn<T> {
    @JsonCreator
    public GenericMessageMixIn(
            @JsonProperty("payload") T payload,
            @JsonProperty("headers") Map<String, Object> headers
    ){}
}
```

And finally all works OK!